# UIBarButtonItem image appears pixelated

Tags: ios, image, uibarbuttonitem

In my IOS app, I'm trying to incorporate images on UIBarButtonItems.  I found some icons on IconFinder, but they appear pixelated when I specify the image using the Storyboard (I exported 22x22 pixel pngs).

It appears fine in the storyboard but pixelated on my device / in the simulator:

[image]

[image]

How can you ensure that UIBarButtonItem images are not pixelated?  I've read that they should be 22x22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be 22 x 22 *points*. You are dealing with pixels.

You need an @2x image that is 44 x 44 as well as an @3x image that's 66 x 66 if you're optimizing for iPhone 6 Plus.

[Here's a helpful link about the difference between points and pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)

Comment: thanks for your help.  what is the point to pixel conversion?

Comment: I've added a link that documents what you're asking about.